# Should I put programs on HDFS?

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Shoud I put programs on HDFS or keep them local?
I am talking about a binary file which is:

- Launched by spark-submit
- Executed daily
- Execute spark map reduce functions on RDD/Dataframes
- Is a JAR
- Weights 20 Mo
- Processes a lot of data, this dfata is located on HDFS

I would think it is a bad idea, since distributing an executable file on HDFS might slow down the execution. I think it would be even worst for a file which is larger than 64 Mo (Hadoop block size). However, I did not find ressources about that. Plus, I do not know the consequences about memory management (is java heap replicated for each node that holds a copy of the JAR?)

Comment: HDFS is designed to store data files, not binary executables. You shouldn't be using it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly the concept behind YARN's shared cache.

The main reason for doing this is if you have a large amount of resources tied to jobs, and submitting them as local resources wastes network bandwidth.

Refer to the Slideshare to understand the performance impacts in more detail:

- Slideshare: [Hadoop Summit 2015: A Secure Public Cache For YARN Application Resources](https://www.slideshare.net/ctrezzo/hadoop-summit2015-yarnsharedcachev12)
- [YARN Shared Cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/SharedCache.html)
- [YARN-1492 truly shared cache for jars (jobjar/libjar)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1492)

Comment: Nice. And without cache sharing, what are the performance consequences?

Comment: That depends on how saturated your cluster workload is.  For Twitter and their large cluster, the cost of distributing job jars to 1000+s of NM is significant.