# How to let spark cluster fetch package jars from local path rather than from master?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I found that every time I launch an application in my spark standalone cluster with external packages, say `pyspark --master=spark://master:7077 --packages Azure:mmlspark:0.17`, executors are always trying to fetch package jars from the driver. Here is the log:

```
2019-05-23 21:14:56 INFO  Executor:54 - Fetching spark://Master:2653/files/com.microsoft.cntk_cntk-2.4.jar with timestamp 1558616430055
2019-05-23 21:14:56 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to Master/192.168.100.2:2653 after 23 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2019-05-23 21:14:56 INFO  Utils:54 - Fetching spark://Master:2653/files/com.microsoft.cntk_cntk-2.4.jar to /tmp/spark-0a60d982-0082-4d37-aea1-e1c0b21ee2be/executor-c9632fd2-29fc-429c-bdfb-31d870ed19e8/spark-15805ad8-ab00-41b3-b466-b0e8e95a3f56/fetchFileTemp5196357990337888981.tmp
```

Something like this repeats in the logs of the executors. The size of the package is quite big, so the process takes a lot of time.

I have tried using `--jars` argument of pyspark to upload required jars to each executor. Executors did fetch them from the local path, but I couldn't import the package in the shell.

So how to solve the problem? What should I do to let the executors fetch the package from the local path? Or maybe from HDFS?

Comment: is it possible to copy the jar to all nodes and add the path to the jar in `spark.executor.extraClassPath` config param

Comment: YARN has a shared cache.   See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863143/should-i-put-programs-on-hdfs for more info.

Comment: @DaRkMaN That seems to work for the moment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for letting know @Y.Yu, I will add it as an answer

Comment: I just realized that my cluster actually ran in the standalone mode, but your solution is still very informative. Thanks all the same! @tk421

Comment: Now that I come to think of it, using `--jars` might work too. I just didn't doing it the right way at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can copy the jar to all nodes and add the path to the jar in `spark.executor.extraClassPath` config param, so that the jars are available in executor's classpath.

Comment: Where is this parameter found - 'spark.executor.extraClassPath. I checked my cloudera instance (single node quickstartVM) but couldn't find this in Spark configuration params.

Comment: It is available in Open source spark. You can find details about it gere: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment